# jQuery if/else statements

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement

i'm trying to write some if/else conditions within a jQuery ajax method. I don't know jQuery well, so i'm probably just making a stupid small syntax error. But here it is:

```
    function swapContent(count,product)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "includes/price-update.php",
                data: {countVar: count, ProductID: product},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('.cleardata').remove();

                    $.each(data, function ()
                    {

                        $(".price-data").append(
                        $("<tr class='cleardata'/>")

                        if (data.InStock == "In Stock") {
                        $('.in-stock-row').text ('Yes');
                        }
                        else if (data.InStock == "Unavaiable"){
                             $('.in-stock-row').text ('No');
                        }
                        else{
                             $('.in-stock-row').text ('-');
                        }
                        .append("<td class='store-row'><h5 property='seller'>" + this.MerchantName + "</h5></td>")
                        .append("<td class='price-row'><h5 property='price'>$" + this.Price + "</h5></td>")
                        .append("<td class='in-stock-row'><h5>" + this.InStock + "</h5></td>")
                        .append("<td class='merch-row'><a property='url' target='_blank' href='" + this.PageURL + "' class='merch-but'>GET IT</a></td>")
                        );
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Everything works great aside from the if/else statments. I'm not sure if `return` is the correct way of echoing out data. I am a PHP guy, so the jQuery is still all new. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I just changed the code according to some suggestions and this is what I have, and nothing in my table is showing up now.

Second EDIT: Attaching an image of JSON data for debugging. 
[image: JSON Data from ajax post method. Not sure why there is a 3 and InStock with the same properties.]

Third EDIT: Posting PHP data

```
<?php
$countVar = $_POST['countVar'];
$ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
$data = PriceCompare($countVar, $ProductID);
echo json_encode($data);

function PriceCompare($countVar, $ProductID){
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=---','---','---');
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT MerchantName, Price, PageURL, InStock
                    FROM merchants
                    WHERE ProductID=' . $ProductID .' AND Count=' . $countVar . '
                    ORDER BY Price');

$result = $STH->fetchAll();

return $result;
}
?>
```

EDIT Four: Fixed the JSON data from getting two sets of the data by changing the php `fetchall` method to `fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` Results of fixed JSON data below. Still not getting the correct results in the In Stock table field though.
[image: Fixed JSON Data]

Comment: Did you mean `else if` in place of your second `if`?

Comment: What is your error, nothing gets returned?  I don't think you need parenthesis in your return statements.  Try taking those out first.

Comment: You will want to specify where you want to echo it out for example
`<div class="response"></div>` would be the container somewhere in your HTML page and then you can do this instead of `return ("Yes");` you would do this `$('.response').text('Yes');`

Comment: No, this should be used as its better: `$("#idname").html("write this");` this would be more like it! As the jQuery has its own API. and by echoing data, you mean to write the variables or the responses you get?

Comment: @brbcoding Instead of return ("Yes") something like console.log("Yes"). Rob has it right

Comment: Return is not the correct way to output in this case. Consider building the message onto a variable and then appending it as a row, just like you are doing below the if/else.

Comment: Consider having a look at this link: http://api.jquery.com/html

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous so you can't use return statements like that

Comment: Not to be that guy, but that's technically JavaScript you're writing, and jQuery is just a library for JavaScript. :-) Also, If I'm right the `data` parameter is a string, and If I remember correctly, if you set this header `Content-Type: application/json`, then jQuery is "clever" enough to parse it for you, too. Also, `return` in JavaScript exits the function and continues execution at the next instruction from where the instruction was called [and optionally puts whatever value on the stack]. Also, the parameters in the anon function inside `$.each` are a bit off, I think.

Comment: @destielstarship since he already specifies `dataType:'json'` in the constructor it will automatically parse the response as a JSON object.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, oh that line went completely over my head! Thanks.

Comment: One other thing to mention is that the `each` function takes a slightly different syntax. I will add an answer with working example.

Comment: I just made an edit, but it didn't fix it. So i'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I appreciate the answer, I'm not sure why its setting all the InStock as "-" when some of the data should display "Yes" or "No"

Comment: @MitchGlenn Can you perhaps post an example of the data you are echoing out of php so we can take a look?  I've also modified the if statements to have an `if else` too in case of the `No` outcome.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I attached the json data, I think thats where the bug is happening, I'm not sure why on each object 3 and InStock contain the same data.

Comment: It seems that you have both and associative array and numeric array being returned by your php script.  Give me a couple of mins and I'll test the scripting.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I also just attached the php. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added some mock JSON, there was a typo in the spelling of `Unavailable` in the first one.  This is only the `each` section of the AJAX success function which is correct.  You can see this working on http://jsfiddle.net/mhWdP/

Hope that helps.
R.

```
JsonData = [{
    "InStock": "In Stock",
        "MerchantName": "Coffee for Less",
        "PageURL": "http://www.google.com",
        "Price": "14.99"
}, {
    "InStock": "Unavailable",
        "MerchantName": "Drugstore",
        "PageURL": "http://www.google.com",
        "Price": "15.99"
}, {
    "InStock": "No",
        "MerchantName": "Drugstore2",
        "PageURL": "http://www.google.com",
        "Price": "29.99"
}];


$.each(JsonData, function (index, dataItem) {
    stockStatus = '';
    if (dataItem.InStock == "In Stock") {
        stockStatus = "Yes";
    } else if (dataItem.InStock == "Unavailable") {
        stockStatus = "No";
    } else {
        stockStatus = "-";
    }

    tempRow = document.createElement('tr');

    $(tempRow).append("<td class='store-row'><h5 property='seller'>" + dataItem.MerchantName + "</h5></td>")
        .append("<td class='price-row'><h5 property='price'>$" + dataItem.Price + "</h5></td>")
        .append("<td class='in-stock-row'><h5>" + stockStatus + "</h5></td>")
        .append("<td class='merch-row'><a property='url' target='_blank' href='" + dataItem.PageURL + "' class='merch-but'>GET IT</a></td>")
        .append("</tr>");

    $(".price-data").append(tempRow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At least two problems:

1. You are returning before you do the `$(".price-data").append` part
2. You are acting on `data` (the list), not any particular element of the list.

It should be something like:

```
                $.each(data, function(i, element)
                {
                    if (element.InStock == "In Stock") {
```